# What causes 0xA4 to become 0xffffffa4 when reading a binary file?

Tags: c

I'm getting unexpected results when loading a binary file in C.

```
FILE *bin = NULL;
unsigned long file_length = 0;

bin = fopen("vs.bin", "rb");
fseek(bin, 0, SEEK_END);
file_length = ftell(bin);
fseek(bin, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *buffer = (char *)malloc(file_length);
fread(buffer, 1, file_length, bin);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < file_length; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

What I see in the first eight values of output is this:

```
56 53 48 05 ffffffa4 ffffff8b ffffffef 49
```

But what I see when I open the binary in a hex editor is this:

```
56 53 48 05 A4 8B EF 49
```

What would cause this to happen? There are more instances of this happening throughout but I thought only sharing the first segment would suffice to illustrate the problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have sometimes found the compiler option `-funsigned-char` useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `char *buffer` to `unsigned char *buffer`. Also change `%02x` to `%02hhx`.

In your C implementation, `char` is signed. When you read data into a buffer of `char`, you have signed values. When you use them in an expression (including arguments to `printf`), some of them have negative values. Additionally, values narrower than `int` are generally promoted to `int`. At that point, the `char` value −92 (which is represented with bits 0xA4) becomes the `int` value −92 (which is represented with bits 0xFFFFFFA4, in your C implementation).

So you have negative values that are converted to `int` and then printed with `%02x`, and `%02x` shows all the bits of the `int`. (In `%02x`, `2` specifies the minimum width; it does not restrict the result to two digits.)

`%hhx` is a proper conversion specifier for an `unsigned char`. `%x` is for `unsigned int`.

Comment: Isn't `%hhx` also proper for `signed char`?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There are language-lawyer questions there I do not want to go into here.

Comment: Ugh! Of course! I'm happy to move past this and embarrassed I didn't catch it myself. Thanks, Eric.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier `%02x` specifies the *minimum* number of digits to be printed out, not the maximum.  The values `a4`, `8b` and `ef` are all negative when interpreted as signed bytes, so what you're seeing is the two's complement representation of these values as 32-bit `int`s, which is what they're promoted to when passed to `printf`.

Explicitly name buffer as `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` to avoid this unintended sign-extension, and use the correct format specifier (`%hhx` for lowercase `a`-`f` hex digits, `%hhX` for uppercase).